# How can, or can you access a group of controls or elements with code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to access a group of controls in ASP.NET somehow?

In jQuery you can access multiple elements using a class="somegroup" like

```
$('.somegroup')...
```

In ASP.NET I understand I can access an element or control using the ID, but is there a way to access multiple controls or elements at once?

For example, let's say I have this in design view:

```
<asp:Label ID="label1" CssClass="someclass"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lbl" CssClass="someclass"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lb2" CssClass="someclass"></asp:Label>
```

Now I want to turn the visibility off on all of them.

**Instead of doing this:**

```
label1.Visible = false;
lbl.Visible = false;
lb2.Visible = false;
```

**Is there an equivalent to this?**

```
someclass.Visible = false;
```

Is there possibly a different tag property I could be using?

using asp.net and C#

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write your own function, pass a string class into it (and optionally a parent control or form) then loop thru Controls collection checking for the CssClass property and making needed modifications for matched controls.

Something like

```
void hide(Control el, string cssClass) {

    foreach (WebControl c in el.Controls)
    {
        if (c.CssClass == cssClass)
        {
            c.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

and call

```
hide(this, "someclass");
```

Comment: OR, you can just inject the jquery bits into the aspx page and control from there?

Comment: I think (might be mistaken) the OP question was about how to do this server-side. Setting control's `visible` to false on server means it wont be rendered at all

Comment: @Aniket - the example the OP gave of visibility makes it seem like they want to control CSS type properties, but I believe the OP wants to have access to any of the server control properties, which jQuery does not.

Comment: How will this work with controls that are not server side? :-) or are nested in other controls?

Comment: @Karl - you are correct. I want access to server control properties. I used Visible as an example. Most importantly, I want it done server side or I would use jQuery. To be more specific, I want to show controls when in Debug, and remove them when I do a Release build.

Comment: @Aniket - all controls will be server side for my particular situation.

Comment: @Aniket of course this won't work for client-only controls, that's the point. And for nested controls there's this thing I heard called recursion (btw, the example above is just that, an example, disclaimer: it is not meant as a full blown ready-to-use, plug-n-pray solution)

Comment: @YuriyGalanter, since we are doing something like Javascript does, on the server side.. I decided to use some functional style programming, and came up with the 'Apply' function. check that out.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void Apply(string selector, Control parent, Action<WebControl> a)
    {
        if (selector.StartsWith("."))
        {
            foreach(WebControl wc in parent.Controls)
            {
                if (wc.CssClass == selector.Substring(1))
                {
                    a(wc);
                    if (wc.HasControls())
                    {
                        Apply(selector,wc,a);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (selector.StartsWith("#"))
        {
            foreach (WebControl wc in parent.Controls)
            {
                if (wc.ID == selector.Substring(1))
                {
                    a(wc);
                    return;//no need to search any further.
                }else
                {
                    if (wc.HasControls())
                    {
                        Apply(selector, wc, a);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Maybe this will help?

then you can do this:

```
Apply(".SomeClass", this, a => a.CssClass="SomethingElse");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no baked-in syntax for doing a selector-type operation in C#.

You can however write your own loop to do this, like this:

```
private void SetAllLabelsWithCssClassValueToInvisible(Control parentControl, 
                                                      string className)
{
    foreach(Control childControl in parentControls.Controls)
    {
        // Try to cast control to a label, null if it fails
        var label = childControl as Label;

        // Check to see if we successfully cast to label or not
        if(label != null)
        {
            // Yes, it is a label 
            // Does it have the correct CssClass property value?
            if(label.CssClass == className)
            {
                // Update the Visible property to false
                label.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Obviously you can expand/improve upon this notion and make it fit your needs, just a proof of concept that is very specific for `Label` controls with a particular `CssClass` value and the `Visible` property.

Internally, the jQuery Sizzle engine is doing this looping for you.